# Android application crashes on start when using android.os.Process.killProcess on onDestroy() method

Tags: android, android-studio, activity-lifecycle

We had a bug on our app, and were (almost)convinced that we solved it putting `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` under `onDestroy()` on main activity.

I say almost because today on tests done with android 4.4.2 on a LG G3 device, the application is stuck in an endless loop at splash screen start up. It starts normally when I remove `android.os.Process.killProcess`. We have this confusion why does this happen since `onDestroy()` is supposed to be called when app  is closed not when you open it.

Do you have any idea why this might happen? Any hint?

Comment: If you use `killProcess()` when your Activity closes, it'll kill any Services, BroadcastReceivers, Jobs or other Activities you may have open. This is an XY problem; consider asking a question about the original "bug."

Answer (score 1):

Killing own process explicitely is bad idea on android. Usually you shall not do this at all - it is responsibility of OS.  onDestroy() on activity can be called at any time OS sees right ( consult activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle ) -for example it it has lost focus.

And activity destruction does not mean that process has to be killed.  And is splash screeen by chance your main activity?

Comment: I know the process doesn't have to be killed on destruction. It was a workaround that seemed to fix the bug we had.Splash screen is not the main activity, is another activity. The bug we have occurs in a scenario like this:  Users opens the app and then puts it in background. Then he clears it from recent apps. Then if he tries to open it again it will not open, it will stuck at splash screen. If he clears it again from recent apps it will open normally. It's an client/server communication app that needs to maintain a session with backend to work normally.

Comment: Another odd things is that, this doesn't occur on device running android 7.0 . Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Without your manifest of core snippets  there is no help possible ( my mind reading skills are pretty low in the morning ). As said in another commentar, killing process disposes everything and kithchen sink assotiated with your app-   And then out of sudden some broadcast or whatever  arrives - and everything is restarted again.  Just to be killed after splash screen